# How to access getter method of bean class using reflection api?

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

Why the value is null for the `variable2` ,  if I instantiate the class using Reflection API?

Where, the value of `Variable1` is returned correctly as per the set and here I instantiated the object normally.
How can I obtain the value of `variable2` using `ReflectionAPI`?

```
    package com.OP.app;

    public class Bean {

    private String variable1;
    private String variable2;
    public String getVariable1() {
        return variable1;
    }
    public void setVariable1(String variable1) {
        this.variable1 = variable1;
    }
    public String getVariable2() {
        return variable2;
    }
    public void setVariable2(String variable2) {
        this.variable2 = variable2;
    }


}

package com.OP.app;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ObjectCall {

    public static void main(String []args){
        Bean beanobject = new Bean();
        beanobject.setVariable1("Ram");
        beanobject.setVariable2("Rakesh");
        System.out.println(beanobject.getVariable1());
        String path = "com.OP.app.Bean";
        Class<?> newClass;
        try {
            newClass = Class.forName(path);
            Object obj = newClass.newInstance();
             String getMethod = "getVariable2";
             Method getNameMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod(getMethod);
             String name = (String) getNameMethod.invoke(obj); 
             System.out.println(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // convert string classname to class
      }
    }
```

**Output :
Ram
null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is beause you are invoking the method on newly created object (e.g. `obj`) which does not have values set for `variable1` and `variable2`, e.g.:

```
Object obj = newClass.newInstance();
```

The above will create a new `Object` of `Bean` class with null values for `variable1` and `variable2`. If you want to print the values set in `beanobject` method then you need to invoke the getter method with `beanobject`. i.e. change

```
String name = (String) getNameMethod.invoke(obj);
```

to

```
String name = (String) getNameMethod.invoke(beanobject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new instance of the target class where no values set.

```
Object obj = newClass.newInstance();         
Method getNameMethod = obj.getClass().getMethod(getMethod);
```

Change this line and it should work:

```
Method getNameMethod = beanobject.getClass().getMethod(getMethod);
```

Additional:
Your naming of variables isn't very good. I would refactoring the code to this for better reading:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bean beanInstance = new Bean();
    beanInstance.setVariable1("Ram");
    beanInstance.setVariable2("Rakesh");

    System.out.println("Value 1 of fresh bean instance: " + beanInstance.getVariable1());

    String beanType = Bean.class.getName();
    Class<?> beanClazz;

    try {
        beanClazz = Class.forName(beanType);

        String getterMethodName = "getVariable2";
        Method getterMethod = beanClazz.getMethod(getterMethodName);
        Object returnValue = getterMethod.invoke(beanInstance);

        System.out.println("Value 2 of by reflection loaded bean instance: " + String.valueOf(returnValue));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // convert string classname to class
}
```

Comment: this will not work: `Class.forName` expects the ful qualified class name, not the package name. However `Class<?> beanClazz = Bean.class;` is easier anyway.

Comment: You are right. The bean class requires the full class name (getName() do this).  'Class<?> beanClazz = Bean.class;' is easier but if the class is only known at runtime you couldn't do anything with hard coded class declaration.